# PHP Mail () function disabled in SMTP impact?

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm experiencing problems with **PHPMailer**, the version of the class is 5.1, which is generating the following error: `Could not instantiate mail function` error that corresponds to an instance problem.

Checking the possible causes of this, I have seen that the `directive:` *disable_functions* is including the **mail()** function.

So when I use it, I get the following error:

> Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons

Given all this, I wonder if the error generated, could not instantiate mail function, is directly related to the lack of this function in php.ini.

**Obs:** The MX server is configured for G Suite, so the SMTP settings are from google gmail.

Comment: Why is PHPMailer using `mail` tho? It can open a socket directly (which is what you should do)

Comment: 1 - you need to include your code so we can help you. 2 - the `mail` function is disabled per the disabled_fucntions which is why you are receiving this warning. 3 - you should be setting PHPMailer to use SMTP which will bypass the use of the `mail` function

Comment: @cmorrissey, code add.

Comment: @Machavity PHPMailer uses `mail()` for sending by default; it require less config than SMTP, but requires that you have a local mail server, though it supports SMTP too of course.

Comment: Base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), and you really need to update; 5.1 is years out of date and is buggy and vulnerable, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 0):

I removed this and resolved it: `$mail->Mailer   = "SMTP";`

Comment: That will work, but use `$mail->isSMTP();` in preference to setting `Mailer` directly.